# Foundation 5 equalizer not working?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Trying to figure out why equalizerr is not worlking with this code. Have been over the docs MANY times & don't see my error.

are there any particular situations, styles/inheritance or something that prevents equalizer from working?

What is wrong with this markup?

```
<div class="row resource-content" data-equalizer="main-layout"><a name="skip-to-content" href="#"></a>


<div class="small-12 columns lead-in">

  <h1>[[*longtitle]]</h1>
  [[*introtext:notempty=`<div class="introtext">[[*introtext]]</div>`]]

</div>


<div class="small-12 medium-6 medium-push-3 columns content-center" data-equalizer-watch="main-layout">

  [[*content]]

</div>

<div class="small-12 medium-3 medium-pull-6 columns sidebar sidebar-left" data-equalizer-watch="main-layout">

  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">

    <h2>[[*left-sidebar-label]]</h2>

    [[*sidebar-left]]

  </div>

</div>


<div class="small-12 medium-3 columns sidebar sidebar-right" data-equalizer-watch="main-layout">

  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">

    <h2>[[*right-sidebar-label]]</h2>

    [[*sidebar-right]]

  </div>

</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Markup looks correct. Might be your script includes. Make sure it looks similar to the below per the docs section under "Using the Javascript".

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: This is what is confusing me ... markup looks good & equalizer does work in the footer elements in the same page!

Comment: @SeanKimball Maybe try not setting a value for both the `data-equalizer` and `data-equalizer-watch` attributes. The documentation examples only use values in these attributes when there are nested equalizer sections. Not sure why that would be the case, but could try it.